# Activate top nav links when scrolling single page with Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, anchorpoint

If you see my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MI5Studio/pen/eKwXXw) you will see that if you click a link, the link will turn red and go to the anchor point section.

I would like to activate the links even when using the scrolling. Anyone knows how?

Other thing that worries me is that when the link is active red and I click in other part of the page the link turns white again.

I'm using Foundation.

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Magellan, which provides this feature:

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/magellan.html

Comment: Daniel, I'm using Magellan but it is not working, thanks for your response

Comment: Dear, I have updated the codepen and it is working but not in my page. I'm a bit confused. I think that Codepen has a js or some configuration that I'm skipping in my web. Could it be this the issue?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console on your website?